# Debug app in eclipse while being in alpha test phase in google play

Tags: android

I know how to debug an app created by myself and having the code within eclipse. Assuming that I have loaded the apk for alpha testing on google play set alpha testers and being able to install it, how can I debug it ?I need steps.. I want to debug the app when a billing transaction occurs, set break points etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a **release** to the Play Store, it cannot be **debuggable** for security reasons. If you want your alpha testers to be able to debug the app, you need to use other methods such as email, or use a beta distribution service that allows you to upload debuggable apps. Personally, I send my builds by email if I know that the person needs to be able to debug it.

Comment: How can I test in-app purchasing then? For example, how do I know that my inventory include items that I put in from Google Play "In-App Products"